# Understanding Self Join

Tags: mysql, sql, self-join

I was practicing **self join** and here's a thing I do not understand in writing query.

I have a table `'employee'`

The employee table contains three records.

```
+-----+---------------+------------+
| id  | employee      | manager_id |
+-----+---------------+------------+
| 1   | Ola           |   NULL     |
| 2   | Ahmed         |    1       |
| 3   | Tove          |    1       |
+----------+----------+------------+
```

Last column manager_id refers to the first column id making Ola manager of Ahmed and Tove.

If I write the query like

```
SELECT emp.employee as NAME, manager.employee as MANAGER
FROM employee as emp, employee as manager
WHERE emp.id = manager.manager_id
```

Result makes Ahmed and Tove Manager.
Whereas

```
SELECT emp.employee as NAME, manager.employee as MANAGER
FROM employee as emp, employee as manager
WHERE manager.id = emp.manager_id
```

Makes it correct, could anyone please explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Self join is like a inner join where two or more instances of same table are joined together through a common data type column/field. Such join(inner join) gives the common rows as result, based on the joining condition.

The employee table contains three records. In this case,

employee as emp:

```
+-----+---------------+------------+
| id  | employee      | manager_id |
+-----+---------------+------------+
| 1   | Ola           |   NULL     |
| 2   | Ahmed         |    1       |
| 3   | Tove          |    1       |
+----------+----------+------------+
```

employee as manager:

```
+-----+---------------+------------+
| id  | employee      | manager_id |
+-----+---------------+------------+
| 1   | Ola           |   NULL     |
| 2   | Ahmed         |    1       |
| 3   | Tove          |    1       |
+----------+----------+------------+
```

**Now First case: Lets try this to understand the difference:**

SELECT `emp.*`, `manager.*`
FROM employee as emp, employee as manager
WHERE emp.id = manager.manager_id

```
+-----+---------------+------------+-----+---------------+------------+
| id  | employee      | manager_id | id  | employee      | manager_id |
+-----+---------------+------------+-----+---------------+------------+
| 1   | Ola           |   NULL     | 2   | Ahmed         |    1       |
| 1   | Ola           |   NULL     | 3   | Tove          |    1       |
+----------+----------+------------+----------+----------+------------+
```

See, emp.id = manager.manager_id . Thus, emp.employee as NAME is giving rows of Ola from first table & manager.employee as MANAGER is giving rows of Ahmed & Tove from the second table.

**Now Second case: Lets try this to understand the difference:**

SELECT `emp.*`, `manager.*`
FROM employee as emp, employee as manager
WHERE manager.id = emp.manager_id

```
+-----+---------------+------------+-----+---------------+------------+
| id  | employee      | manager_id | id  | employee      | manager_id |
+-----+---------------+------------+-----+---------------+------------+
| 2   | Ahmed         |    1       | 1   | Ola           |   NULL     |  
| 3   | Tove          |    1       | 1   | Ola           |   NULL     |
+----------+----------+------------+----------+----------+------------+
```

See, manager.id = emp.manager_id . Thus, emp.employee as NAME is giving rows of Ahmed & Tove from first table & manager.employee as MANAGER is giving rows of Ola from the second table.

Answer (score 1):

Writing WHERE emp.id = manager.manager_id does not make much sense, because manager (or the row you want to display as a manager) does NOT have a manager_id. I.e you must start with emp.manager_id because you want to list employees and to each manager_id of that employee you want to list the corresponding manager.

Answer (score 1):

`manager.employee` will give you the correct name only if you JOIN on `manager.id`
which only happens in the second query.

The alias of the table which uses `id` in the ON condition MUST be the same
which uses `employee` column,so `manager.id`->`manager.employee`.

Answer (score 1):

For each row, `manager_id` refers to the employee's manager.  This is described by your second query.  Here you match `emp.manager_id` to the employee in the joined table.  The asserts that the relationship exists because of the id column -- in other words, Ola's manager is anyone with a `manager_id` of 1.  In this case, both Ahmed and Tove have a manager_id of 1, so they both match.  HTH.